# Resolve error SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake using org.glassfish.jersey.client

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jersey, jersey-client

I'm using Jersey-client-2.27 through which invoking https get call as shown below:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

return client.target(url)
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("authorization", token)
        .get(String.class);
```

Getting below exception once in every 10-15 call hits at client get() method:

```
"status":500,
"reason":"Internal Server Error",
"code":0,
"message":

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$1(JerseyInvocation.java:767)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:765)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:428)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:324)
```

What could be the reason for failing API call frequently especially during load testing and how can I resolve it? I already tried ignoring SSL certificate and adding x509 certificate while sending a request

Comment: It doesn't look like your client is doing anything wrong. You'd have to look at the logs on the server to figure out why it's dropping the connection.

Comment: I haven't seen any errors from server logs. Looks like client itself failed while communicating.